# ajax request gets images from server 20 at a time, how to stop sending request when there no images left?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

i jave a function ajaxRequest that retrieves images from server (c# action method) how can i stop sending request when there no images left?

I thought sending the count of images in html code and if the count is 0 stop sending is this correct ? But i have to parse someway the comments from html. Is there better way to do this?

The ajaxRequest function executes every  2 seconds with timeOut.

Code:

```
ajaxFunction = function() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            clearTimeout(loadFromServerTimeout); // clear the timeout until THIS request ends.

        },
        type: 'get',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "GreekFurs")',
        data: {
            skip: value
        },
        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
            // data is html from server
            loadFromServerTimeout = setTimeout(ajaxFunction, 3000); // Start the timer again.


        },


    });
}
```

AJAX view from server:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    var photos = (List<ShoppingGalleryPhoto>) ViewData["data"];
}
 <!--count:@photos.Count-->
@foreach (var photo in photos)
{

     <li><a></a></li> //image links
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the number of `li` elements returned. If there are 20 (ie. the limit), you need to send another request. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if ($(data).filter('li').length == 20) {
        loadFromServerTimeout = setTimeout(ajaxFunction, 3000); // Start the timer again.
    }
},
```